# Are PEX joints required at the shower valve?

Tags: plumbing, shower

Almost every shower valve install I’ve seen has 90 degree joints on both sides to hot and cold, is there some reason why I can’t run it like this without joints? Less joints the better right? [image]

Comment: What are you referring to by "PEX joints"? Do you mean 90-degree elbow fittings? Something else? Maybe edit your question and add a pic of these "PEX joints".

Comment: Not a plumber, but I think pex has radius specs.  If the bend is allowed by those specs it should be okay.  They would exert a bit extra stress on the centre joint and having elbows/90 degree joints seems a bit more professional looking.

Comment: @crip659 I would install clips to hold it to the studs so there isn’t much stress

Comment: If everything else is good, then having four less joints to maybe leak is better.

Comment: There are many plumbers who treat PEX as if it were rigid pipe, either from fossilized brains or from "more profit in every fitting sold" I can't tell you which for sure, or both may apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For cold bending, the minimum bend radius under ASTM F876 6.12.3 is 6 times the outer diameter. For 3/4" PEX, that's 6(0.875") = 5-1/4" (measured to the inside of the bend) so your configuration is okay for 1/2" or 3/4" PEX. That ASTM specifies the outer diameter as nominal diameter plus 1/8". That ASTM calls for support at both ends of the bend.

The change of direction of flowing water exerts a force on the tubing, so you need to restrain its movement at the bend. I suspect that the familiar pattern with an elbow close to the valve puts the short stub of PEX to work in bending to restrain movement. I suspect that this makes the familiar pattern more forgiving for installers who don't bother with restraining the tubing against movement.

Comment: I’m a little confused what “minimum” radius means. Do you mean the maximum radius?

Comment: @Michael, the bend radius is the radius of a circle that matches the inside edge of the bent piece (sometimes it's the midline of the bent piece or even the outside edge of the bent piece, but not in this case). In the limit, a bend radius of zero is a kink. In the other limit, a bend radius of infinity is a straight line. You want to stay away from the kink at radius zero, hence the minimum.

Answer (score 2):

It's going to be more common to see elbows simply because the minimum bend radius adds up. Pair two minimum bends with the valve and you're likely to end up with a wider assembly than the spacing of your framing.

If your framing allows for the correct bend radius, or if you would prefer to cut holes to get in to the adjacent bay than to add fittings, I can't see any problem with installing with bends only. You should use some sort of support for the bend.

Comment: OTOH, the large radius bends have less headloss! :)

Comment: Precisely why I avoided as many fittings as possible on my re-plumb.